# Credit cards are always declined by Realex Payments

Tags: php, payment-gateway, realex-payments-api

I am using the redirection method of Realex Payments gateway. It's redirecting correctly to their server, but when I proceed with live card details it's showing that it's processing. After completion of the process am getting the message below.

> Your transaction has been declined. Please contact your credit card provider to find out why your card was declined.

This is how I am sending the details:

```
<form action="https://epage.payandshop.com/epage.cgi/" method=post>
<input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_ID" value="<?=$merchantid?>">
<input type="hidden" name="ORDER_ID" value="<?=$orderid?>">
 <input type="text" name="CURRENCY" value="<?=$curr?>">
 <input type="text" name="AMOUNT" value="<?=$amount?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="TIMESTAMP" value="<?=$timestamp?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="MD5HASH" value="<?=$md5hash?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="AUTO_SETTLE_FLAG" value="1">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Proceed to server"/>
 </form>
```

Comment: Are you using test card details?

Answer (score 2):

If you are under test mode you should use test card details. To get those details you have to contact the realex support. First make sure you in test mode or not. If you are on test you will be provided a test merchant ID and a test shared secret. I would suggest you to use test mode since you are still developing the system. Above error message means your card was declined by bank due to one of the following reason

- Invalid Card Number
- Invalid Amount
- Invalid Currency
- Invalid Expire Date
- Invalid Merchant
- Invalid Transaction
- Not authorised card
- Retailer Unknown

So make sure your parameters pass the right data. Live card will not work if you are on test mode.

Answer (score 1):

This message means that the bank has refused the transaction and the payment has not succeeded. This can happen for many reasons, but the most common are that the card has exceeded its limit, or that perhaps the wrong expiry date has been entered. Check the transaction in RealControl to find the result code which will give you more information.

One other thing, there should not be a trailing slash '/' after 'epage.cgi' in your code.

Owen